# Question on tower property

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

in a book of mine it says that for sub $\sigma$-algebras $\mathbb D \subset \mathbb E$
$$
\mathrm E [X \mid \mathbb D]
=
\mathrm E [
\mathrm E [ X \mid \mathbb E ]
\mid \mathbb D ]
=
\mathrm E [
\mathrm E [ X \mid \mathbb D]
\mid \mathbb E ] 
$$
The first equality I recognize as [the tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), but the later I cannot make sense of.
If $\mathbb E \not = \mathbb D$, then I can find $E \in \mathbb E$ subject to $E \not \in \mathbb D$ where it should hold that
$$
\int_E
\mathrm E [
\mathrm E [ X \mid \mathbb D]
\mid \mathbb E ] 
dP
=
\int_E
E[X \mid \mathbb D] dP
$$
but $E[X \mid \mathbb D]$ is only $\mathbb D$-measurable. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that if $X$ is $\mathbb F-$measurable, then $$\mathbb E[X\mid\mathbb F]=X.$$

Since $\mathbb E[X\mid \mathbb D]$ is $\mathbb E-$measurable,

$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X\mid \mathbb D]\mid \mathbb E]=\mathbb E[X\mid \mathbb D].$$

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. :)

Comment: @bubububub: I edited my answer.